# C#: Map strings and binary data

Tags: c#

I have several external devices that share the same functionalities with different protocols.
Some require plain ASCII strings, others binary data.

Right now I have different look-up tables to retreive the related codes. Example:

```
static class DeviceA
{
    public static readonly byte[] CMD_1 = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02 };
    public static readonly byte[] CMD_2 = new byte[] { 0x03, 0x04 };
}

static class DeviceB
{
    public static readonly string CMD_1 = "command 1";
    public static readonly string CMD_2 = "command 2";
}

...
```

When I need to send out a command through an I/O interface I have to:

- select the right class (somewhere I have an enum to store the current device)
- convert (if needed) the different data types to the one accepted by the send function (no matter if byte[] or string, it doesn't change the question)

Instead, I'm looking for a way to "map" each device command into one table.
This would let me to easily retrieve the correct command:

```
Commands[currentDevice].CMD_1
```

What is the right approach here?

Comment: What I don't see is how you would then "send" the command to the device... You probably have multiple "send" commands, one with `byte[]` and one with `string`... You must begin solving the problem from there.

Comment: You're already stating your desired approach, you just want the implementation for it. Just use a map with the key being the enum or string of the device and the values being a struct/class which contains the commands for a device. You would then initialize This global map with the device structure instances that you need. A different approach is to have different device classes that are interchanged by your context object (sender) whenever the current device changes.

Comment: @xanatos I would have only one "send" function, say `send(byte[] msg)`. That's why I said I have to convert data - in this example string to byte[].

Comment: @o_weisman Yes, but I'm open to better suggestions!

Comment: I gave you another suggestion. It's not necessarily better, just different.Do you need a code example for it?

Comment: @o_weisman Am I wrong or it's exactly what I'm doing now? As said, I have "different classes that are selected in function of the current device". It ends up to use a lot of `if` or `switch` to select the right one.

Comment: It depends on the amount of logic you need to perform in the device classes. If all you need is to get a specific set of commands, then your map approach is fine. If however, you need to perform all sorts of logic based on the current device, I would suggest the strategy pattern which is the second option I gave as it only leaves a single case which selects the current device usually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
public interface IDevice
{
    byte[] CMD_1 { get; }
    byte[] CMD_2 { get; }
}
```

so an interface describing all the possible commands.

Then one stateless class with only a singleton for each device:

```
public class DeviceA : IDevice
{
    public static readonly DeviceA Instance = new DeviceA();

    private DeviceA()
    {
    }

    public byte[] CMD_1 { get; } = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02 };
    public byte[] CMD_2 { get; } = new byte[] { 0x03, 0x04 };
}

public class DeviceB : IDevice
{
    public static readonly DeviceB Instance = new DeviceB();

    private DeviceB()
    {
    }

    public byte[] CMD_1 { get; } = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("command 1");
    public byte[] CMD_2 { get; } = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("command 2");
}
```

and then somewhere:

```
Dictionary<string, IDevice> devices = new Dictionary<string, IDevice> 
{
    { "Device1", DeviceA.Instance },
    { "Device2", DeviceB.Instance },
};
```

and when you need to use it:

```
var cmd = devices["Device1"].CMD_1;
```

Other possibility, a generic `GenericDevice` class that can be "configured" at runtime:

```
public class GenericDevice
{
    protected bool isReadOnly;

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return isReadOnly; }
        set
        {
            if (isReadOnly && !value)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }

            isReadOnly = value;
        }
    }

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (isReadOnly)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
            name = value;
        }
    }

    private byte[] cmd_1;

    public byte[] CMD_1
    {
        get { return cmd_1; }
        set
        {
            if (isReadOnly)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
            cmd_1 = value;
        }
    }

    private byte[] cmd_2;

    public byte[] CMD_2
    {
        get { return cmd_2; }
        set
        {
            if (isReadOnly)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
            cmd_2 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
var deviceA = new GenericDevice
{
    Name = "Device A",
    CMD_1 = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02 },
    CMD_2 = new byte[] { 0x03, 0x04 },
    IsReadOnly = true,
};

var deviceB = new GenericDevice
{
    Name = "Device B",
    CMD_1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("command 1"),
    CMD_2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("command 2"),
    IsReadOnly = true,
};

var devices = new Dictionary<string, GenericDevice>
{
    { "Device1", deviceA },
    { "Device2", deviceB },
};
```

Note that you can still subclass the `GenericDevice` to add "special commands", and through the `Name` property you can differentiate between devices.

Comment: Interesting! My lack was the second layer of abstraction (interface above device classes). I will try it right now.

Comment: @Mark Other way added.

Comment: I prefer to use types instead of strings, in the above approach: use a `Dictionary<Type, IDevice>` to store the devices, and you can build a generic method like `T ResolveDevice<T>()`.

Comment: Just a thought: don't think you want to expose a property with a setter for the commands as they should be hardwired to the protocol an should only be changed by the devices themselves. Also, not sure you really need a dictionary of devices when using this approach, as the classes are singletons.

Comment: @o_weisman For this reason there is a `IsReadOnly` that is "settable"... There are three "patterns" for these things: the constructor that sets everything and creates an immutable object, the "Builder" (like `StringBuilder`) that creates an immutable object and the mutable-until-made-readonly that I'm using. The constructor pattern is the easiest, but having many parameters (many commands  = many parameters) it is normally frowned upon.

Comment: I'd still suggest exposing only getCmd() instead of exposing the command properties. Good answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would take xanatos suggestion further, and incorporate the send method to the interface. The details of how the command is sent belongs to the device implementation.

```
public interface IDevice
{
    public void SendCommand1();

    public void SendCommand2();
}

public class DeviceA implements IDevice
{
    public void SendCommand1()
    {
        // send new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02 }
    }

    public void SendCommand2()
    {
        // send new byte[] { 0x03, 0x04 }
    }
}

public class DeviceB implements IDevice
{
    public void SendCommand1()
    {
        // send "command 1"
    }

    public void SendCommand2()
    {
        // send "command 2"
    }
}
```